# Why I enter the captcha file path in url it return a binary file instead an image file

Tags: php

Why I enter the captcha file path in url it return a binary file instead an image file, but when I use in img tag every thing work well.
this is my captha file

> 

```
<?php
  session_start();
  ob_start();
  //$captchaText = strtoupper(substr(md5(microtime()), 0, 5));
  $captchaText=rand ( 100000 , 999999 );
  $_SESSION['captcha'] = $captchaText;

  $image = imagecreate(230, 70);
  $background = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 239, 239, 239, 1);
  $textColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, mt_rand(0, 100), mt_rand(0,255), mt_rand(0,255), 1);
  $x = 25;
  $y = 50;

  for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $fontSize = mt_rand(30, 50);
    $text = substr($captchaText, $i, 1);

    imagettftext($image, $fontSize, 0, $x, $y, $textColor, './captchafont/bnazanin.ttf', $text);

    $x = $x + 17 + mt_rand(0, 10);
    $y = mt_rand(40, 65);
            $textColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, mt_rand(0, 255), mt_rand(0,255), mt_rand(0,255), 1);
             $linecolor=imagecolorallocatealpha($image, mt_rand(0, 255), mt_rand(0,255), mt_rand(0,255), 1);
        imageline($image,mt_rand(0, 230) , mt_rand(0, 70) ,mt_rand(0, 230), mt_rand(0, 70), $linecolor);
        imageline($image,mt_rand(0, 230) , mt_rand(0, 70) ,mt_rand(0, 230), mt_rand(0, 70), $linecolor);

  }

  header("Content-type: application/jpeg");
  imagejpeg($image);
  imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after years I want to answer my old question and I forgot to close it

the problem was about the header, the header should be as below

```
header('Content-type:image/png');
```

that's it all.

Answer (score 0):

This command might be failing, thus it's sending output before your headers output.

```
imagettftext($image, $fontSize, 0, $x, $y, $textColor, './captchafont/bnazanin.ttf', $text);
```

Make sure the font is one folder above inside "captchafont" folder, refering to this php file path.

Try commenting that line and you should see at least the image rendering with some lines across it.

Comment: when i use it in html img tag every thing is ok
<img id="captcha_image"  src="./ap-captcha.php" />
but when i want to access the captcha in url it send a binary file.
127.0.0.1/.../.../ap-captcha
why it does not show the captcha image

Comment: probably you have error reporting off so an img src="" can be interpreted by the browser and outputted correctly. but if you try to open the file directly, there's no "translation" of the file.

Comment: so why when i want to open the captcha of other website directly in the url bar it show an captcha image? is that mean they print image tag in captcha file??

Comment: the problem is either in the font file or the headers for the content-disposition.